# Unable to get whole data from Arraylist<Object[]> data from another method in java

Tags: java

I have done returning list from one method and trying to receive the list data from another method to write in excel file but it is printing only last row.
please help me where i am missing the part. thanks in advance.
1.Method one readingFile is reading the text file
2. Second method is to writing file from the list data received from method one

My code with two methods  are as follows

```
   package one;  
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class AutoPasswordReset 
{
    public String input_path = ("C:\\Users\\RAVI\\Desktop\\Skills\\inputs");
    public String output_path = ("C:\\Users\\RAVI\\Desktop\\Skills\\outputs");
    BufferedReader br;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:MM.ss");
    SimpleDateFormat parsingSdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:MM.ss a");
    Object[] received = new Object[3];
    static ArrayList<Object[]> list= new ArrayList<Object[]>();

    public  ArrayList<Object[]>  readingFile() throws IOException{
        try{
            File fi = new File(input_path);
            File[] fileCount = fi.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0;i<fileCount.length;i++){
                File file = fileCount[i];
                if(file.isFile()){
                    System.out.println("Total file count : "+fileCount.length);
                    String fileName = file.getName();
                    System.out.println("File name : "+fileName);
                    String data;
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input_path+"\\"+fileName));
                    while((data = br.readLine())!=null){
                        if(data.contains(">")){
                            String dat = data.substring(data.indexOf(" ")+1,data.indexOf("-")-1);
                            //System.out.println(dat);
                            Date date = sdf.parse(dat.substring(dat.indexOf(" "),dat.lastIndexOf(".")));
                            //System.out.println(date);
                            String timeFormat = parsingSdf.format(date);
                            //System.out.println(timeFormat);
                            received[0] = dat.substring(dat.indexOf("0"),dat.indexOf(" ")+1)+timeFormat;
                            //System.out.println(received[0]);
                            received[1] = data.substring(data.indexOf("<")+1,data.indexOf(",")-1);
                            //System.out.println(received[1]);
                            received[2] = data.substring(data.indexOf("Target"),data.lastIndexOf("."));
                            //System.out.println(received[2]);
                            list.add(received);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException | ParseException fe){
            System.out.println(fe.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
    }
    public  void writingFile(ArrayList<Object[]> list){
        try{
             /*for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                    Object[] obj = list.get(i);
                    System.out.println(obj[0]);
             }*/
            AutoPasswordReset apr = new AutoPasswordReset();
        ArrayList<Object[]> listTwo = apr.readingFile();
        for(Object[] data : listTwo){
            System.out.println(data[0]+" "+data[1]+" "+data[1]);
            //Unable to get all datas it is printing only last row from file
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        AutoPasswordReset ar = new AutoPasswordReset();
        ar.writingFile(list);
        // Unable to pass as argument after changed to non static variable 

        try{
        }catch (Exception fnt){
            System.out.println(fnt.getMessage());
            fnt.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's happening because you are always adding the same reference to the same `static Object[] received`.

Rather than declaring a single one at the class level, you should declare a new one for each line being read.

Comment: Hi Radiodef i made non static variable but still i am not able to pass list as argument from main let me update my code again in above screen

Comment: Hi Patrick parker i have updated my code again and posting still not working thanks for your time and helping me out

Comment: please read more carefully my comment and the answers in the linked duplicate. It explains exactly what you have done wrong.

Comment: Patrick Parker bro i have read those and did modified variables to non static
now in main method i am not able to pass list it is showing me to change it to static again

ar.writingFile(list);
  // Unable to pass as argument after changed to non static variable

Comment: i have added after entire loops in try block then it is running only once instead of for 21 times for 21 rows with last row patrick

Comment: It is not working still now

Comment: Where i have to modify exactly tried all possible inside and outside loops to add objects into list   list.add(received);

Comment: It's better not to use arrays in conjunction with `List`s. You could instead, for example, use `List<List<YourType>>`.

Comment: Can you please tell me more specific patrick. in the end of try block i added 
list.add(obj);   then also it is not working

Comment: Hi MC Emperor , i am not sure where you are pointing out i am facing problem in 
below two declaration 
1.  static ArrayList<Object[]> list= new ArrayList<Object[]>();

2.  Object[] received = new Object[3];

Comment: why list adding last row for 20 times can anyone help me where i am doing wrong

Comment: just removing the word "static" is not enough. you have not understood my comment or the linked answers. try reading them again or ask in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java).

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to chat you can tell me more specific i could understood to avoid adding to same reference what i have to do patrick plz help me thanks

Comment: Is anyone help me , fine let me add all my codes into main method to fix... thanks guys

Comment: what part of this comment is confusing? "declare a new Object[] received for each line being read". You have to ***move*** the ***declaration*** to your inner loop of the read function.

Comment: Hi Patrick bro, i just declared inside while loop where it is starting to read and it is working fine now.


while((data = br.readLine())!=null)        
{
Object[] received = new Object[3];

why bro what does the difference it take, i just declared an object array with size of 3 right
and adding each column after substring from a file to add

why it is not worked before bro....Thanks much , and when u find free time plz update why it is not worked before. thanks again Patrick bro

Comment: so what i can understand is each time object array need to be created to add each line i mean row from a file, is that right bro Patrick...

Comment: I think you should study the explanation in the linked duplicate. In particular, what is a Java reference variable and how can two variables point to the same object.